# Is there any way to check in RenderScrpt if an rs_allocation has been bound properly?

Tags: android, renderscript

Whenever I define

```
rs_allocation abcd;
```

in my renderscript, I am afraid I will forget to bind it from Java, leading to cryptic issues. Is there any way to write

```
if (abcd == NULL)
    rsDebug("Error");
```

or

```
if (!rsIsValidAllocation(abcd))
    rsDebug("Error");
```

etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this...

```
if(!rsIsObject(abcd))
```